# Filter json array data in spark dataframe

Tags: arrays, pyspark

I have spark dataframe that I am converting into JSON format:

```
json = df.toJSON().collect()
print(json)

['{"lot_number":"4f19-9deb-0ef861c1a6a1","recipients":[{"account":"45678765457876545678","code":"user1","status":"pending"},{"account":"12354567897545678","code":"error2","status":"pending"}]}', 

'{"lot_number":"09ad-451e-8fb1-50bc185ef02f","recipients":[{"account":"4567654567876545678","code":"user3","status":"pending"},{"account":"12354567876545678","code":"user2","status":"pending"}]}']
```

I need to filter the data from array, that is all recipients whose code is "user1".

I'm expecting this result:

```
['{"lot_number":"4f19-9deb-0ef861c1a6a1","recipients":[{"account":"45678765457876545678","code":"user1","status":"pending"}' 
]
```

Can anyone help to filter the data as shown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you will need to convert the `string` in the `list` to `dict` objects.

```py
import json

json_rdd = df.toJSON().collect()
json_ls = [json.loads(x) for x in json_rdd]
```

```
# Now you can filter using "user1"
final_json_ls = [x for x in json_ls if x.get("recipients")[0].get("code") == "user1"]
```

If you have multiple recipients:

```py
new_list = list()
for lot in json_ls:
    recs = lot.get('recipients')
    lot_recipients = [rec for rec in recs if rec.get("code") == "user1"]
    if lot_recipients:
        new_list.append({"lot_number": lot.get('lot_number'),
                         "recipients": lot_recipients})

# OUTPUT
# [{'lot_number': u'4f19-9deb-0ef861c1a6a1', 'recipients': [{u'status': u'pending', u'account': u'45678765457876545678', u'code': u'user1'}]}]
```

And since you want to convert it back to json to send POST requests:

```
for ls in new_list:
    lot = ls.get("lot_number")
    url = "test.com/api/v1/notify/request/"+ batch
    response = requests.put(url, data=item, headers=headers) 
    print(response.text)
```

Comment: Thank you pissall, i have given example array above. I have many recipients details with user1. Does it work if i remove [0] from get("recipients")[0]? or any other way we need to follow?

Comment: Then you will have to loop with a list comprehension on recipients as well.

Comment: The second cmd is still returning both recipients details (user1 and error2) from the first lot. Not returning expected result.

Comment: I have updated my answer. I am trying to convert it to a list comprehension.

Comment: Thank you. It is returning the below output.

Comment: [{'recipients': [{'code': 'user1', 'account': '45678765467876545678', 'status': 'pending'}, {'code': 'error2', 'account': '123545678976545678', 'status': 'pending'}], 'lot_number': 'f1cbc6d4f19-9deb-0ef861c1a6a1'}]

Comment: Is it expected?

Comment: Expected result is [{'recipients': [{'code': 'user1', 'account': '45678765467876545678', 'status': 'pending'}], 'lot_number': 'f1cbc6d4f19-9deb-0ef861c1a6a1'}] –

Comment: It should return all recipients where code is 'user1'

Comment: So you want `recipients` and not `lot_numbers`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am looking to filter the data at array. From each lot, i want to filter recipients based on filter condition.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you so much. Is there anyway we can convert this list back to JSON format? because i want to send this details to API using PUT. I have tried this data = json.loads(new_list)... but throwing an error "the JSON object must be str, not 'list'

Comment: Yeah. Just use [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) on the `new_list`

Comment: Updated my answer as well

Comment: Working perfect pissall. The below code was working perfect earlier. But not sure why it is not working even though we converted it back to JSON.

Comment: for item in json_final:
#Get the lot number in each iteration to pass it to URL
    Getlot = json.loads(item)   
    lot = Getlot['lot_number']
    url = "https://test.com/api/v1/notify/request/"+ batch  # Pass the batch number in each iteration
    response = requests.put(url, data=item, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)

Comment: I can't understand the code from comments. Please add it to your question or ask a new one, because it is unrelated to the already asked question.

Comment: You are using `json.loads()` again. That is converting it back to python data structure from JSON. You need to comment the line `Getlot = json.loads(item)` and `lot = item.get("lot_number")` should be it.

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake to ask irrelevant question, i tried the same solution but since it is string, giving an error ''str' object has no attribute 'get''. So thought to check with you.

Comment: Edit my answer to finish your solution.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable time. Unfortunately it is still throwing same error for the line  lot = ls.get("batch_number")

Comment: @user11899725 I'm sure you're doing it wrong. You still have a string'd object. Follow my exact code from the top. Remove any dumps or loads that you might have added yourself. Only use the code in this answer.

Comment: Sure pissall. I will follow the code and recheck. Thank you for all your time and help me with the solution. I will upvote this.

Comment: i have followed all steps and just stuck with one error at end. Does it change type of any field? Also i am looking to update the code from 'user1' to 'user2' using put request. Can we hard code this while passing?

Comment: This is the error: {"code":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request validation failed","details":["The property '#/' of type array did not match the following type: object in schema updateRequest"]}

Comment: @user11899725 replace ‘json.dumps(item)’ with just ‘item’

Comment: Thank you, i believe item means ls here. I have tried with the solution. But different error i can see

Comment: {"code":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request validation failed","details":"Could not parse the JSON request body"}

Comment: {"code":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request validation failed","details":"Could not parse the JSON request body"}

Comment: above result for  print(response.text)

Comment: Sure, one moment

Comment: {'lot_number': 'e2881a4b-c1f1-4d79-8552-6e96339396bb', 'recipients': [{'account': '1520183489562796194956309577', 'status': 'completed', 'code': 'user1'}]

Comment: What are your `headers`? Are you sending the right request? The output for `item` can definitely be JSON parsed.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what's the problem. Because my actual code is working good if i do not filter data at array level. I am using same header for this method and the one you seggested.

Comment: data = Mongodata.toJSON().collect() 

 for item in data:
    Getlot = json.loads(item)   
    lot = Getlot['lot_number']

    url = "https://test.com/api/v1/notify/request/"+ batch 
    response = requests.put(url, data=item, headers=headers)
    print(response.text)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200049/discussion-on-answer-by-pissall-filter-json-array-data-in-spark-dataframe).

Comment: Sure, your are life saver. Thank you pissal. I will open a separate thread as i want to update status to 'ready' from 'completed' while sending this data to API.

Comment: Thank you Samuel, i will used 'moved to chat' for further discussion with pissall.

Comment: @pissall, if possible could you join on chat?

Comment: Thank you for all your inputs and support @pissall. Worked the solutions provided with one change data=json.dumps(ls)

Comment: @pissall if you get few min please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58176757/data-update-though-put-request