# Data update though PUT request

Tags: python-3.x, api, web-services

I am processing the below data (sample data) to API however while sending this data, i want to update the status to 'done' from 'ready' since next time when it runs, these recipients should be excluded and new recipients will available with 'ready' status.

```
data = [{'lot_number': 'a53f-8fb40cabab7e',
'recipients':
[{'status': 'ready', 'account': '1001'}, 
 {'status': 'ready', 'account': '1002'}]}, 

{'lot_number': 'ad3d-a0849d5c7c7a',
'recipients':
[{'status': 'ready', 'account': '1015'}, 
 {'status': 'ready', 'account': '1019'}, 
 {'status': 'ready', 'account': '1023'}]}]


for final_data in data:
    batch = final_data.get("lot_number")
    url = "https://ext-api-support-dev.llws.com/api/notify/"+ batch
    response = requests.put(url, data=json.dumps(final_data), headers=headers)
```

The above code is working perfectly and sending the response successfully. Right now there are three fields (lot_number, recipients.status, recipients.account) that we are processing however i need to process only recipients.status, recipients.account only and recipients.status should be updated to 'done'.

For example let's assume that we have 100 lots in data with 50 recipients in each lot, i want to update the status to 'done' in each loop. Even though if response gets failed in the middle of process (20 lots processed and got failed) i want to update the status for all processed batches (first 20 lots).

Since we can update the data using put, can we do any changes in data=json.dumps(final_data) in response and process?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Thanks @pissall for all input and i tried using below code but there is no luck. Also i am looking to update this while processing the data instead of doing it after response success.

Comment: if response.status_code == 200:
    for rec in final_data.get("recipients"):
    rec["status"] = "done"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this:

```py
done_lots = list()
url = "https://ext-api-support-dev.llws.com/api/notify/{0}"
for final_data in data:
    batch = final_data.get("lot_number")
    # Remove the lot_number
    request_data = {k: v for (k, v) in final_data.items() if k != "lot_number"}
    response = requests.put(url.format(batch), data=json.dumps(request_data), headers=headers)
    # Loop over recipients and update status
    # THIS DOES NOT UPDATE TO THE DATABASE. IT ONLY UPDATES THE final_data variable
    for recipients in final_data.get("recipients"):
        recipients["status"] = "done"
    done_lots.append(final_data)
```

Comment: Thank you pissall. I tried this earlier, not sure why data is not getting updated in database, so i though this loop must be part of response. I will double check and upvote this response. Actually, we are fetching 3 fields ((lot_number, recipients.status, recipients.account), however lot_number is only required to make it as part of URL in each loop, but should not be part of posting data. Is there anyway we can omit/exclude field in response (data=json.dumps(final_data))

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Hi @pissall, it is throwing an error of 'invalid syntax' for 4th line 'request_data'. I tried by removing k,v at starting but still did not work. Thanks for last two lineS to change the status, does this loop execute before actual response send? Because i believe it should be executed before request send. If it work as such, it will be fine else we can hard code this even in  request_data  while removing lot_number. Any suggestion, i can try if syntax error get solved.

Comment: It could be simple requirement but finding hard time to get it on. Just need to request using put with two fields 1. lot_number 2.status with hard coded values send. API will update this in DB.

Comment: It doesn't update before sending the request. But I was assuming you would update it, after sending the request. What if the request fails? Also, if your requirement is to update before sending request, you can just move the for loop before sending request.

Comment: Got it @pissal. I just tried and it is not updating even successful completion. Actually we would get lot of data in each, lets assume one million recipients. When we loop through each recipients, the status of that recipient should be updated to done. I could be failed may be after loading half million recipients but at least we can avoid reprocessing these half million in next load by updating the status. If i move this for loop before sending request, hope it would not update status for all one million recipients if it fails half million. I am not sure with idle scenario but just want2check

Comment: The `request` and `updating` are two different processes. The request corresponds to 1 `lot_number` where as the update corresponds to the number of `recipients`. The request will send data for one `lot_number`, and the second for loop will update all the recipients `status` to `done`. Even if there are millions of recipients.

Comment: Also using above code, it is only processing last lot in the list. I am trying with 3 lots and if i check print(response.text), it is showing only last lot and status got updated for last lot (i moved for loop before sending request)

Comment: Thank you, the request and updating details are very clear. Just for cross check, i have tried with two lots and again last one updated.

Comment: That is because we didn't put it outside the first for loop. I will fix my code to do that

Comment: I am not overriding your variable `data`, rather creating a new list to add the lots that are done called `done_lots`

Comment: Working as expected. Thanks for your time.